# Symfony form validation behavior

Tags: symfony

I have a simple form linked to a DB object.

If I use annotations to add validation constraints to my object

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @Groups({"link_idea:read"})
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
private $url;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
private $esIndex;
```

errors are displayed on top of the form:

[image]

If I implement the validation constraints in the form class

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
    ->add('Url', UrlType::class, ['constraints' => [new NotBlank()]])
    ->add('EsIndex', null, ['label' => 'Index', 'constraints' => [new NotBlank()]])
    ->add('save', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Save'])
    ;
}
```

errors are displayed below each field:

[image]

This is the behavior I want as this is more user-friendly. But using annotation seems to be the recommended way and also cleaner from a coding point of view.

Is there a way to use annotation and get the second behavior?

Comment: What happens when you match the exact case-sensitive property name like `->add('url'` and `->add('esIndex'` ?

Answer (score 0):

Annotation is not the preferred way to make a form field required.

When building a form in symfony, you can use the `required` option as mentioned in the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#the-required-option)

Your form builder should look something like this

```
 $builder
    ->add('Url', UrlType::class, [
        'required' => true,
    ])
 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there’s a way to use annotations and get the second behavior, you just have to define `form.error(form.THE_FIELD_NAME)` in the twig file that contains the form https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#form-errors-form-view

Comment: This does not work. The error is still rendered in the global form errors.